# Optimizing a parameters vector for an unknown system to minimize error rate

Tags: optimization

Not sure this is the correct form for this question. If not please migrate it.

I have a vector of parameters $x\in \mathbb R^n$. This vector contains configurations for a system (say a receiver). We have a numerical indication $e$ of how well the system preformed (in this case a bit error rate meter). The lowest $e$ is the better the system performed since this is an error rate.The general goal is to minimize $e$ using $x$.

I thought of taking a gradient descent approach though I have no formulation connecting the values of $x$ to $e$. $x$ here, contains configuration values for an unknown system and is not exactly an input. furthermore, I have no information on dependencies between different $x(j)$ entries.

The elements of $x$ are integers (discrete values) with different intervals for each entry $x(j)$.$e$ Is measured physically (reading a digital value from the system).

- Is there an algorithm which resembles gradient descent which can offer an optimization for this kind of a problem?
- If not, what is the best I can do here? What is the best approach?

Comment: Can you evaluate e without error (noise), or only a noisy estimate, and if so, can you control the level of noise? Is evaluation of e by physical experiment, or do you have a computer simulation? Are all elements of x continuous, or are there integer (discrete) restrictions on some elements? What do you mean by contingencies between different x entries?  Is that referring to constraints (restrictions) on allowable values of x, individually or in combination?  Are there constraints on x?

Comment: @MarkL.Stone. See edits to my post. I cannot evaluate $e$ without errors. This is the error rate and the term I wish to minimize. The goal is to control the level of noise, that is, to choose the values of $x$ which minimizes the error rate. contingencies are my mistake and where fixed to dependencies. There are no constraints on $x$ other than a different interval for each $x(j)$ and the fact that all entries are integers.

Comment: What is the numerical value of n? How many distinct integer values are there for the various elements of x?  Does the response vary "continuously" relative to changes in elements of x, even though they are restricted to integer values? For instance, if an element of x were temperature, settable in one degree increments, then the response might behave in a continuous manner relative to that element, even though it can only be evaluated at discrete points. As opposed to 1 for on, 0 for off, which behaves in a very discontinuous manner.

Comment: Relative to noisy evaluation, I'm talking about whether bit error rate can only be evaluated imperfectly, i.e., with an error in the bit error rate. Can you control the length of run, or whatever, used to evaluate bit error rate, thereby affecting the accuracy with which it is evaluated? Or do multiple "independent" runs with the same value of x, and use the averaged result?

Comment: The value of n for my case is 743 and the error rate can only be integers as it is the bit error rate (the number of bits misinterpreted by the receiver). I wish to keep the question general though. The discrete nature and dimension of my specific problem are of less importance.

Comment: I can control the length of the run. I am safely assuming same length for each run.

Comment: The discrete nature of the problem is very important (it makes the problem harder). And value of n is important to determining what is practical.  If number of bits is high enough, the measured bit error rate could effectively be continuous. You can think of run length as being analogous to batch size in (stochastic) gradient descent, and your ability to control it can be very useful.

Comment: As best as I am familiar, the stochastic gradient descent uses a constant batch size. Is there an algorithm with a dynamic batch size that can help? I am still confused regarding how to implement a gradient descent considering I do not know the mathematical relation between $e$ and $x$. What do I use as the derivative?

Comment: So-called mini-batch allows different batch sizes. Difficulty or impossibility of evaluating derivative is very relevant. That's why I asked many of the questions. If things behave continuously enough, you might be able to judiciously use a derivative-based method.

Comment: I am not sure I am following you. Is the derivative method the basic one? If so, I am not sure how to implement it?

Comment: With discrete variables, you normally can't. Bit if the variables are "continuous" enough, maybe you can. Otherwise, you need something for discrete problems, which will wind up being rather heuristic, and might not work that well for a problem as large as yours.